# Mulithreading does not help for IO intensive task?

Tags: linux, multithreading, hard-drive

I need to copy a set of files with the size of each file ranging from 1MB to 700MB. After I copy each file, I need to validate the checksum of each file against an entry in md5sum.txt.

I wanted to optimize this task and hence evaluated the performance by splitting the load among multiple threads. The results were not as expected. I was expecting that the time taken for copy and validation would decrease with increase in the number of threads, but the time taken actually increased.

I have modified the ThreadPool source code shared in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/22285532/1568395 to implement the threadpool.

The source code for the application can be found here
https://github.com/saai63/ThreadPool

The results for various number of threads is as shown below,

[image]

As per my reading, the probable reason could be that all tasks are now IO bound tasks and hence all of the threads will be blocked on IO operation and hence cannot run in parallel as the shared resource here is the HDD. I also understand that HDD controller tries to optimize the disk access by reducing the seek time. Disks love sequential access patterns, and any concurrent accesses will disrupt this pattern and hence the delay for large files.

Is this the only reason for the delay or there are some other factors? Why does the time increases with the increase in number of threads?

Comment: Threadpools aren't a data parallelism technique. They're a low-level feature used by data parallelization code but don't offer anything themselves. You could create 5 "workers" that each handles 1/5th of the files. Those workers could get their threads from that pool, but in the end, it's data partitioning and the workers that will speed up things. You won't get a 5x performance boost though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : I was not expecting the time to be reduced by a factor of 'n' but at least better than what is achieved through a single thread. The results seen were counter intuitive and hence the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IO is always much slower than the CPU.  When multiple threads try to read from an IO device, what they usually achieve is a "bull rush" to the device and increase the "randomness" of the IO operations, thus making it all slower.  Fewer threads have a greater chance of sequential operations, which are notoriously faster.

Comment: Ok. Can the same be be extrapolated to processes too?
If there are 2 processes trying to simultaneously copy some data to the same partition, then both the processes will be slowed down?
Is this behavior just random or its always the case?

Comment: Yes.  It is threads, not processes, that get time from the OS scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Multithreading you share CPU amongst threads. CPU is swtichted amongts threads whenever running thread goes into some sort of waiting state.

Here you have IO bound task and, there's no point of making your program multithreaded as all of them will be relying on single IO device.

Even if you implement a multiprocess solution (multiple processes on same node), all processes will be waiting for the same IO device and won't give any performance optimization.

One solution would be building some sort of multi node solution with shared disk having simultaneous multi-client access support.

Using this kind of approach you can divide your task amongst multiple nodes, access same disk and perform operation.

Edit:

I think increase in time is beacause time taken by Operating System for servicing multiple threads.

Switching CPU and IO devices amongst thread is gonna take as you increase number of threads, Context Switch is compute intensive task as well as you lose the IO/CPU Cache performance as you switch amongts threads.

Comment: But that still doesn’t explain the huge 10 fold increase as soon as I employ multiple threads to do the job

Comment: @saai63 I have edited my answer, I hope it explains.